# COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ...) doesn't work when grouped by week

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to count all tickets that are currently assigned to a specific department, grouped by the date (calender week) the ticket got assigned to the department.

### What I need

I want to count all tickets that are assigned to department A, grouped by the week they were assigned, to see:

A) How many tickets are currently assigned to dep A

B) When they were assigned / How long they have been assigned

**Note:** A Department can assign a ticket to themself, to assign a new editor. I'm only interesed in the assignments from one department to another (**except** for when it's the very first action, which would mean that the assigned department also recorded the ticket).

### Problem

It is possible that a ticket gets assigned more than once to the same department (let's say once on the 1st of january and again on the 15th of february, after department A assigned the ticket to department B on the 4th of february).

Now, if I "count(distinct..." all tickets assigned to department A grouped by week, naturally the distinct statement only applies for each week and not for the entire data set. But what I actually want is the very last assignment to that department. Otherwise it would falsify the information about how long all the tickets have been processed by the same department.

### Existing table

| ticket no | action | date actioned | calender week actioned | actioning department | assigned department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 012934 | assignment | 01.01.2022 | 52 | A | A |
| 012934 | investigation | 01.01.2022 | 52 | A | A |
| 012934 | assignment | 06.01.2022 | 1 | A | B |
| 012934 | stop service time | 06.01.2022 | 1 | B | B |
| 012934 | start service time | 17.02.2022 | 7 | B | B |
| 012934 | assignment | 20.02.2022 | 7 | B | A |
| 083333 | assignment | 08.03.2022 | 10 | C | A |
| 236211 | assignment | 03.01.2022 | 1 | A | A |
| 236211 | investigation | 03.01.2022 | 1 | A | A |
| 236211 | assignment | 06.01.2022 | 1 | A | A |
| 236211 | stop service time | 22.01.2022 | 3 | A | A |

### Expected result

| Calender week | Count A |
| --- | --- |
| CW 1 | 1 |
| CW 7 | 1 |
| CW 10 | 1 |

### Actual result

| Calender week | Count A |
| --- | --- |
| CW 52 | 1 |
| CW 1 | 1 |
| CW 7 | 1 |
| CW 10 | 1 |

As you can see it looks like there are four tickets currently assigned to department A, one of them being processed since CW 52 2021, when it's actually the same ticket that got re-assigned to dept A in CW 7 as you can see in the table.

### What I've tried

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ar.date_actioned,'YYYY') || ' KW' || TO_CHAR(ar.date_actioned,'IW')  AS "CW"
, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN zsd2.serv_dept_sc = 'A'                -- currently assigned to A 
                      AND(zsd.serv_dept_sc = 'A'                  -- all records where A was assigned AND
                      AND actt.act_type_n = 'assignment'          -- the action was an assignment AND
                      AND (dsd.serv_dept_sc <> 'A'                -- (the actioning department wasn't A OR
                      OR psd.serv_dept_sc = 'A'))                 -- the recording department was A)
                            THEN inc.incident_id END) AS "A"                           
, COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN zsd2.serv_dept_sc = 'B'
                      AND(zsd.serv_dept_sc = 'B'
                      AND actt.act_type_n = 'assignment'
                      AND (dsd.serv_dept_sc <> 'B' 
                      OR psd.serv_dept_sc = 'B'))
                        THEN inc.incident_id END) AS "B"
FROM act_reg ar 
INNER JOIN incident inc on inc.incident_id = ar.incident_id
INNER JOIN serv_dept zsd on zsd.serv_dept_id = ar.ass_svd_id            -- assigned department
INNER JOIN serv_dept zsd2 on zsd2.serv_dept_id = inc.ass_svd_id         -- currently assigned department
INNER JOIN serv_dept dsd on dsd.serv_dept_id = ar.SERV_DEPT_ID          -- actioning department
INNER JOIN serv_dept psd on psd.serv_dept_id = inc.serv_dept_id         -- recording department
INNER JOIN act_type actt on actt.act_type_id = ar.act_type_id
WHERE inc.inc_status = 'o'                                              -- ticket still has to be open
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ar.date_actioned,'YYYY') || ' KW' || TO_CHAR(ar.date_actioned,'IW');
```

Comment: You could write `with cte as(select ticketNumber, max(date) group by ticketNumber) select ticketNumber, week(date) weekNo,count(*) from cte`

Comment: Obviously you're CTE would include your code above, just modified to get max(date) instead of count. This also avoids the need of DISTINCT

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example using the code I posted above? I tried using the cte statement, but since I've never worked with one before it unfortunately didn't work...

Comment: Please could you give you the table definition and an insert to create some sample data and I'll try to write a query for it.